# Jquery preventDefault not working on android 4.4 default browser

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, angularjs

I am working with a angular and jquery based website. I have a text input field for validating array of floating numbers. My requirement is to restrict the user from entering alphabets, etc.

The problem is I am using `e.preventDefault()` but its not working in android default browser but working perfectly in android chrome.

I have searched a lot but unable to get any solution.

My sample code :-

```
 $('#test').keydown(function (e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      e.returnValue = false;
      e.cancelBubble = true;
      return false;
});
```

I have also tried :-

```
$('#test').keydown(function (e) {
  if (e.preventDefault) {
       e.preventDefault();
    } else {
       e.returnValue = false;
  }
});
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7v75690p/)

Note:- I cannot use `keypress` event as the android default browser cannot listen this event.

Comment: Have you tried using an `input type="number"` support for it is pretty common now: http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number

Comment: I cannot use `type=number` as the validation is for array floating numbers which can receive -/+/,/. also. The number keypad will not  allow me to enter this keys.

Comment: Instead of e use 'event.preventDefault'. Beacuse in ANdriod e is undefined

Comment: Have another look at the jQuery documentation. The argument a jQuery handler receives isn't the raw event object. It **always** has `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation`, even if the underlying browser doesn't, and setting `returnValue` or `cancelBubble` on it is pointless.

Comment: @JqueryKing: Er, no, not if the user is using jQuery.

Comment: Try `return false` at the **end** of your code

Comment: @g3mini: Well I did that. Its in the code also.

Comment: @g3mini No it didn't :(

Comment: I understand if you don't want to use a number type input because you need support for IE8, but I don't understand your comment that you can't use it because it doesn't support floating point numbers.  The specification specifically states that floating point is to be supported: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/datatypes.html#common.data.float.  Have you tested?

Comment: @jme11 My inputbox validates for array of comma separeted floating numbers and the numbers can be + or - also. So that is the reason why I cannot use `type=number` since the user won't be able to enter those characters in numper keypad.

Comment: https://github.com/AlphaGit/ng-pattern-restrict/blob/master/src/ng-pattern-restrict.js  You might want to use this plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also had this problem with default browser on Android. preventDefault didn't help me, so I used .on jQuery function.

```
    $('#test').on('input',function () {
        var inputText = $(this).val();

        var resultText = inputText.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
        $(this).val(resultText);
    });
```

You can add to regex the other characters you need to be allowed. Hope it helps.

Comment: Full documentation can be found here: https://api.jquery.com/on/. The function simply attaches an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements. I attached my function on input event to the element that has id '#test'. I get the text that is on that field and replace the characters i don't need([^0-9] -> everything that is not a digit) with ''. I assign the new value to the '#test' field.

Comment: You should also handle `paste` events.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you want to prevent a key event, but I think you just want to prevent entering of invalid chars. Let's see how you could resolve your problem without `preventDefault`:

```
(function(){ // anon function for scope

    var prevVal = $("#test").val(); // get initial value of input

    $('#test').on("input", function (e) { // input will also handle paste event. it handle every input'
        if(/*your `if` here*/ Math.random() > 0.3){
            this.value = prevVal; // You shall not pass!
        }
        prevVal = this.value; // save current valid value
    }); 

})();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rk5wuubo/

I hope, it will solve your problem everywhere and never forget about "paste"!

Comment: I have tried with old value but the input was flickering for that. Still I will try your solution and if it works then I will select your answer.

Comment: For angular based application it's absolutely incorrect answer, because angular model is not updated in the listener provided above.

Comment: it can be resolved by single $apply in the end of validation function.

Answer (score 2):

If you are developing website based on angular you should solve the problem in angular way.

[Here](http://goo.gl/dUzBhF) the sample how to do this.

The idea is to use [NgModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) and [FormController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController).

Comment: I have tried with angular validation but my requirement was a bit more than that as I wanted to restrict the user from inserting any invalid inputs. My only problem was happening in android default browser.

Answer (score 1):

Please use `$formatters` of angularjs. This will help you check the `viewValue` before it is set to `modelValue`.

Please go through this document: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController