# jquery keydown return false doesn't work on android chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this input type="text" in my html that I'm assigning the keydown event to it using jquery as below:

```
$('#refNumber').keydown(function(e) {
    console("key code is " + e.keyCode);

    var val = $(this).val();
    if(val.length == 30) {
        if(e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 37 || e.keyCode == 39 || e.keyCode == 9) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

now the event is fired because I can see the log in the console but the `return false` when the input's value reaches 30 characters does work when I user desktop browser or mobile firefox & ios chrome browser but it doesn't work on android mobile chrome

Comment: Firstly, you should use `e.which` which is normalized in jQuery instead of `e.keyCode`. Secondly, how do you debug your code? What do you get regarding `e.keyCode` compare to what you expect?!... And what about `val`? All what i meant is are you sure your issue has something to do with `return false;`?

Comment: @A.Wolff I've changed the code to log and then return false and it doesn't work. Still can write in the input. And it only happens in android chrome.

Comment: Maybe this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30452057/367865