# event.preventDefault() not working for android chrome

Tags: javascript

event.preventDefault() not working on Chrome Android OS. Whereas the same action is working on chrome IOS.
I even used event.stopPropagation(), event.stopImmediatePropagation().

HTML:

```
 <input class="otherAmount" type="text"id="pVal" name="pVal" onkeydown="validatePaymentToTwoDecimal(this,event);"/>
```

Java Script:

```
function validatePaymentToTwoDecimal(el, evt) {

        if(!$.isNumeric(evt.key)|| evt.key=="."){
            evt.preventDefault();
            evt.stopPropagation();
            evt.stopImmediatePropagation();
            return false;
        } else {
              return true;
        }
}
```

Comment: Which type of event are you handling?

Comment: keydown.Though the onKeyDown returns false still i see the key value in the html field.

Initially i tried using Keypress. Keypress doesn't work on android and works on IOS. So moved to keydown

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: if(!$.isNumeric(evt.key)){ 

         evt.preventDefault();

      evt.stopPropagation();

        evt.stopImmediatePropagation();
            return false;
     }

Comment: is `evt` defined? Show all relevant code and provide a [mcve]

Comment: Is the code ever reached on Android? Try changing some text content from within the event handler and see if the change happens on Android.

Comment: Yes. It did reach android in debug mode. I can see it returning false. But still i see the key value in the HTML field

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery preventDefault not working on android 4.4 default browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30253404/jquery-preventdefault-not-working-on-android-4-4-default-browser)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on [an answer for a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30452057/1071200), you should be able to do this to filter the input:

## jQuery solution

```
$("#pVal").on(
    "input change paste",
    function filterNumericAndDecimal(event) {
        var formControl;

        formControl = $(event.target);
        formControl.val(formControl.val().replace(/[^0-9.]+/g, ""));
    });
```

## Vanilla JavaScript solution

```
var pInput;

function filterNumericAndDecimal(event) {
    var formControl;

    formControl = event.target;
    formControl.value = formControl.value.replace(/[^0-9.]+/g, ""));
}

pInput = document.getElementById("pVal");
["input", "change", "paste"].forEach(function (eventName) {
    pInput.addEventListener(eventName, filterNumericAndDecimal);
});
```

This works by removing digits and decimal point characters using a regular expression.

Comment: This solution has a small issue: the cursor jumps to the end of the line if you enter an invalid char in the middle of your input. You would have to track selectionStart and setSelectionRange to replace the cursor at initial position. And that is impossible to do in the same event loop so you would have to use setTimeout(f(), 0)... and that would make your cursor flicker to the end of the line and back...

Comment: Interesting, @magom001. I am sure that it can be solved though.

Comment: @LarsGyrupBrinkNielsen, if you do find a solution I would be thankful if you shared. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution would be using `textInput` event instead

```
const inpt = getElementById('pVal')
inpt.addEventListener('textInput', evt => {
    evt.key = evt.data
    if(!$.isNumeric(evt.key)|| evt.key=="."){
            evt.preventDefault();
        } 
})
```

It works in Android Chrome

Answer (score 0):

**The only solution that worked for me on Android to filter chars on input**

Android does not allow to catch input of certain chars on `keydown` event. Alternative is to use `input` event. I tried it, but it had problems with caret, that jumped to wrong position while typing in some cases.

I’ve solved it like this:

```js
let input = document.getElementById('input')

function withoutForbiddenChars(str){
    return str.replace(/[^\d]+/g, '')
}

function handleInput(event) {
    let charsBeforeCaret = input.value.slice(0, input.selectionStart)
    let charsAfterCaret = input.value.slice(input.selectionStart)
 
    charsBeforeCaret = withoutForbiddenChars(charsBeforeCaret)
    charsAfterCaret = withoutForbiddenChars(charsAfterCaret)
    
    input.value = charsBeforeCaret + charsAfterCaret
    
    let newCaretPos = charsBeforeCaret.length

    input.selectionStart = newCaretPos
    input.selectionEnd = newCaretPos
}

input.addEventListener('input', handleInput, false)
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/udovichenko/pen/vYWWjmR

Answer (score 0):

In Angular, I use the following directive's code, which can be used as an android alternative to preventDefault

```
 @HostListener('input', ['$event'])
    public onInput(event) {
      let val: string = this.el.nativeElement.value;
      const position = this.el.nativeElement.selectionStart;
      if(event.data == '.' && val.split('.').length > 2){
        //This restricts the additional decimal.
        this.el.nativeElement.value = val.slice(0, position-1);
      }
      //This will add default decimal if not entered manually
      if (val.length == 9 && !val.includes('.')) {
        this.el.nativeElement.value = val + '.';
      }
    }
```

Full code available here=> https://stackoverflow.com/a/74622576/8323774