# preventDefault not working on ionic on <input type="number">

Tags: android, html, ionic-framework, number-formatting, preventdefault

I am trying to build a input field which will only take number as input so it's input type is number. But I want limit the number lenght to 6 digits, using below code

*home.html*

```
<ion-item text-left >
     <input type="number" (keypress)="delimiterClainNo($event, $event.target.value)" id="claim" placeholder="Claim No." (ngModel)]="claim" />
</ion-item>
```

*home.ts*

```
export class HomePage {

  claim : string;
  amount : number;
  status : string;
  expenseType : string;
  description : string;
  beneficiary : string; 

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private alertCtrl: AlertController) {
  }

  delimiterClainNo(event: Event, value: string){

     if(value.length > 5) {
          event.preventDefault();
     }
  }



   display(caption : string, value : any): void { 
       let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
       title: caption,
       subTitle: value,
       buttons: ['Close']
     });
     alert.present();
   }

 }
```

1) This should work on mobile device. Not works on my Android 4.4.2 (Samsung Galaxy Note 2).

2) Works fine on browser and android emulator, but not in mobile.

**System Info**

cli packages: (C:\Users\vcinq\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.12.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.12.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.1
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.4
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.1
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.0.2
Node              : v6.11.2
npm               : 3.10.10
OS                : Windows 10
```

Misc:

```
backend : legacy
```

Can anybody help me? I've been banging my head 'cause of this more thana headbanger attending to a Slayer concert.

Comment: Try using `return false` after `preventDefault` or change the `keypress` to `keydown`

Comment: This doesn't work. Same behavior, doesn't work on android device, works on web and emulator.

Comment: Seem like it is a know issue of preventDefault. You can see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42011740/event-preventdefault-not-working-for-android-chrome) for some work arounds

Answer (score 2):

Little late, but might help others:

Even in Ionic 6, I had the same issue with the slightly different usecase not to allow minuses, commas and dots as input. Also, `keydown` and `keypress` events did not execute `preventDefault()`.

However, `beforeinput` does:

```
 <ion-input (beforeinput)="onInput($event)" type="number"></ion-input>
```

So you can keep your backend logic and just might exchange the handler in the HTML.

Comment: yes man, too late. I've abandoned the idea of learn Ionic some days after have posted this question. Sorry dude...