# Limit input field to two decimal places - Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

The code is as follows

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" value="" name="cost_price" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="item.cost_price" placeholder="Cost Price"  />
```

User should not be able to type more that 2 decimal places.

For example, if the user wants to enter 21.256. He should be only allowed to enter 21.25

How to achieve this using angular 5?

Comment: I would use a validator for the input field or number pipe like this -  item.cost_price | number : '1.2-2'

Answer (score 70, accepted):

First create Directive for limit the two decimal places in typescript like this:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
  selector: '[appTwoDigitDecimaNumber]'
})
export class TwoDigitDecimaNumberDirective {
  private regex: RegExp = new RegExp(/^\d*\.?\d{0,2}$/g);
  private specialKeys: Array<string> = ['Backspace', 'Tab', 'End', 'Home', '-', 'ArrowLeft', 'ArrowRight', 'Del', 'Delete'];
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
  }
  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
  onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    console.log(this.el.nativeElement.value);
    // Allow Backspace, tab, end, and home keys
    if (this.specialKeys.indexOf(event.key) !== -1) {
      return;
    }
    let current: string = this.el.nativeElement.value;
    const position = this.el.nativeElement.selectionStart;
    const next: string = [current.slice(0, position), event.key == 'Decimal' ? '.' : event.key, current.slice(position)].join('');
    if (next && !String(next).match(this.regex)) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}
```

Inject Directive in your `app.module.ts`.
In your html use that directive like this:

```
<input type="textbox" [(ngModel)]="InputValue" appTwoDigitDecimaNumber>
```

Here is working example in Angular 4/5/6:  [Limit Two decimal places number validation](https://stackblitz.com/edit/limit-two-digit-decimal-place)

Hope this will help you!!!!

Comment: hi.this is a good code but found a bug:if user select the existing  2 decimals content with dbl click default behavior is to overwrite the content on a key press,in the above directive will try to append it that calling event.preventDefault() and the control seems like to be readonly

Comment: Your answer is working fine but when we try to edit value before decimal, then it is not allowing me to input any number.  @Sanoj_V

Comment: @GobindGupta thanx for sharing issue. Now it's fixed!

Comment: Yes it is fixed. Thanks @Sanoj_V

Comment: One Improvement I would make is to add a `const positionEnd = this.el.nativeElement.selectionEnd;` to catch circumstances where the user might be trying to type over a selected range of the input.  

Then you can use endPosition for the end slice to cut out the selected characters: `const next: string = [current.slice(0, position), event.key == 'Decimal' ? '.' : event.key, current.slice(endPosition)].join('');`.  

You can also rename `position` as `startPosition` to keep everything consistent.

Comment: Thanks **@Griffin**, your suggested improvement is useful.

Comment: I found an issue in your code. after typing the values i just wanted to select all by pressing the ctrl+a button but it is not working. try to add this also if possible.

Comment: NOTE this doesn't work for input type=number on chrome anymore

Comment: How to restrict user to enter max 10 digit only before decimal and two after decimal?

Comment: WARNING: With this code you can still input any text if you use a non-keyboard input method, such as voice recognition on a mobile device.

Comment: Why does this not work on type="number" input fields?

Comment: @PawanPillai input with `type="number"` does not support selectionStart. Check this [HTML docs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#do-not-apply)

Comment: I can see that this solution works in the StackBlitz that you've created, but for some reason it doesn't work in my project. If I have more than 2 digits, the decimal point doesn't work, and it allows three digits beyond decimal, if I only have 2 digits to the left of the decimal.

Comment: Because of other comments, I removed the type of the input, and now it works. `type="number"` does not work.

Answer (score 5):

@Sanoj_v and user3803848 solution works great, but there is one more bug in IE. When user uses dot sign from numeric keyboard, there is emitted 'Decimal' key event and directive not work properly.

Fix for this:

```
    const next: string = [current.slice(0, position), event.key === 'Decimal' ? '.' : event.key, current.slice(position)].join('');
```

Just in case, I added '.' and ',' char to regex, that checks user input.

Below whole directive

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appTwoDigitDecimalNumber]',
})
export class TwoDigitDecimaNumberDirective {
  private regex: RegExp = new RegExp(/^\d+[.,]?\d{0,2}$/g);// user can put . or , char.
// input also cannot start from , or .
  private specialKeys: Array<string> = ['Backspace', 'Tab', 'End', 'Home', '-', 'ArrowLeft', 'ArrowRight', 'Del', 'Delete'];

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
  }

  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
  onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (this.specialKeys.includes(event.key)) {
      return;
    }
    const current: string = this.el.nativeElement.value;
    const position = this.el.nativeElement.selectionStart;
    const next: string = [current.slice(0, position), event.key == 'Decimal' ? '.' : event.key, current.slice(position)].join('');
    if (next && !String(next).match(this.regex)) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}
```

You should remember, that is still possible to paste some wrong data into input. That's why, you probably need one more validation, maybe on Input event to prevent pasting wrong data.

Answer (score 4):

Answer provided by @Sanoj_V can be improved:

1) you cannot use the arrow keys to edit the number, you can just add digits at the end or you have to click where you want to change the number.

2) once you have two decimals inserted you can only use backspace so either removing the last decimal or clicking somewhere else and removing a digit, but you cannot add anything so you can't change a digit by replacing it.

To solve that just replace : `private specialKeys: Array<string> = ['Backspace', 'Tab', 'End', 'Home', '-'];`

by:  `private specialKeys: Array<string> = ['Backspace', 'Tab', 'End', 'Home', '-', 'ArrowLeft', 'ArrowRight'];`

Then replace: `let next: string = current.concat(event.key);`

by: `const next: string = [current.slice(0, position), event.key, current.slice(position)].join('');`

then add this line just above: `const position = this.el.nativeElement.selectionStart;`

Thanks @Sanoj_V for this directive, I've spent all day trying to figure out how to deal with currencies input.

Answer (score 4):

*Leveraging pau's answer,* this solution works correctly:

In your HTML:

```
<input type="text" (keypress)="decimalFilter($event)" />
```

In your code:

```
decimalFilter(event: any) {
   const reg = /^-?\d*(\.\d{0,2})?$/;
   let input = event.target.value + String.fromCharCode(event.charCode);

   if (!reg.test(input)) {
       event.preventDefault();
   }
}
```

The key difference is that you **append the current text value** ... and allow **0-2** decimal values after the decimal (from 1-2) - then you need to escape '.' otherwise it's treated as an 'any character'.

Comment: What happens, if the user edited the value in midle of the text box, instead of at the end

Answer (score 3):

I am using [ng2-currency-mask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-currency-mask), it is pretty useful. it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm using it for the currency controls now, but it doesn't work for my controls where the decimal is optional, but wanted to limit to two places. I appreciate your sticking it out here where I can find it, though. Very useful.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way to achieve that would be binding to the "keypress" event and validate with a regex expression whether that's a valid input or not.

```
<input type="number" ... placeholder="Cost Price"  (keypress)="validateNumber($event)" />
```

And then the `validateNumber` would be something like:

```
validateNumber(e: any) {
    let input = String.fromCharCode(e.charCode);
    const reg = /^\d*(?:[.,]\d{1,2})?$/;

    if (!reg.test(input)) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: it does not work for me. looks like input is only assigned the current character not the whole value.

Answer (score 1):

This question is several years old, but it helped me immensely. Many thanks to @Sanoj_V and everyone else who's answered here.

I did want to add my take on it, since it may similarly help someone else. I made some changes, as I do not need to allow negative numbers, and since my form will be used to paste 11 digit numbers, I need to allow paste as well as typing.

Here is my directive:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appTwoDigitDecimaNumber]',
})
export class TwoDigitDecimaNumberDirective {
  // Allow decimal numbers, no negative values
  private regex: RegExp = new RegExp(/^\d*(\.\d{0,2})?$/g);
  private specialKeys: Array<string> = [
    'Backspace',
    'Tab',
    'End',
    'Home',
    'ArrowLeft',
    'ArrowRight',
    'Del',
    'Delete',
  ];

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  //capture keys and ctrl-v
  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) onKeyDown(e: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (
      this.specialKeys.indexOf(e.key) !== -1 ||
      (e.key === 'v' && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
      (e.key === 'v' && e.metaKey === true)
    ) {
      return;
    }
    let current: string = this.el.nativeElement.value;
    const startPosition = this.el.nativeElement.selectionStart;
    const endPosition = this.el.nativeElement.selectionEnd;
    const next: string = [
      current.slice(0, startPosition),
      e.key == 'Decimal' ? '.' : e.key,
      current.slice(endPosition),
    ].join('');
    if (next && !String(next).match(this.regex)) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }

  //capture right-click paste event
  @HostListener('paste', ['$event']) onPaste(e: ClipboardEvent) {
    return;
  }
}
```

I've added a couple cases for the CTRL-v on Windows and Command-v on Mac, as well as a HostListener for the paste event.

In the template I've added a (paste) property:

```
(paste)="handlePasteTwoDigit($event.clipboardData.getData('text/plain'))"
```

In the component, I've added a method to handle the paste:

```
 handlePasteTwoDigit(e) {
    var regex = new RegExp(/^\d*(\.\d{0,2})?$/g);
    if (regex.test(e)) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

This can be seen working here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/limit-two-digit-decimal-place-gcfsak

Again, thank you to all who contributed here.

Answer (score 0):

Below coding is to make textbox to allow numeric field with two decimal places(above two decimal places will give warning),without using regex:

abc.component.html:

```
<div >
                                <input class="" type="text" [(ngModel)]="" value="" (keyup)="" [disabled]="" (keypress)="numberOnly($event)">
                                <span class="d-block ml-2">NumericBox(two decimal places)</span>
                            </div>
```

abc.component.ts:

public dotCount:number=0;

```
numberOnly(event): boolean {          
    const charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;      
    if (charCode == 46) {
        this.dotCount += 1;
        this.checkNumberOnly = (event.target.value);
        var numericCheck = (event.target.value).toString();
        if (numericCheck.includes('.')) {
            this.dotCount += 1;
        }
        if (this.dotCount > 1) {   
            this.dotCount = 0;
            return false;
        }
    }
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 45 || charCode > 57 || charCode==47)) {
        return false;
    }
    this.checkNumberOnly = (event.target.value);
    if (this.checkNumberOnly != null) {
        var numeric = (event.target.value).toString();
        if (numeric.includes('.')) {
            var checkNumeric = numeric.split('.');
            if (checkNumeric.length > 2) {
                return false;
            }
            this.checkString = checkNumeric[1].split('');
            if (this.checkString.length > 1) {
                this.toastrService.warning("Invalid value", "Warning");
                return false;
            }
        }

    }
    this.dotCount = 0;
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
    return true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If one is particularly seeking for 2 decimal digit use RegExp(/^\d*.?\d{0,1}$/g);
It start from 0 index till 1 , thus allowing only 2 decimal digits

Comment: Should this regex be put in patter attribute in html or you meant to update an answer after the value is filled by user? Please update your answer to an extend that anyone seeking an answer to this question will be able to achieve wanted result without browsing for additional explanation

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1:

The esiest way I found to do it with `type=number` is:

**html**

```
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="price" (keypress)="currencyCheck($event)"></input>
```

**ts**

```
currencyCheck(event): boolean
  {
    let pattern = /^\d+\.?\d{0,2}$/;
    let result = pattern.test(event.key);
    if (this.price == null)
      return result;
    else
      return pattern.test(this.price.toString() + event.key);
  }
```

But it will not always work if the user add digit in the middle of the number.

### Solution 2:

The following solution will always work but if the input is not according to the pattern it will show the new input for a second before it fix it:

**html**

```
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="price" (keyup)="currencyCheck()"></input>
```

**ts**

```
  currencyCheck(): boolean
  {
    let pattern = /^\d+\.?\d{0,2}$/;
    let result = pattern.test(this.price);
    if (!result) 
      this.price = this.old_price;
    else 
      this.old_price = this.price;
    return result;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work on Android too, in restricting the decimals.
Note that event.preventDefault(), event.stopPropagation() or event.stopImmediatePropagation() won't work on Android. Instead, we can use the 'input' event to override the value of the element as per our requirements.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[OnlyDecimal]'
})
export class OnlyDecimal {
    private regex: RegExp = new RegExp(/^\d*\.?\d{0,2}$/g);
private specialKeys: Array<string> = ['Backspace', 'Tab', 'End', 'Home', '-', 'ArrowLeft', 'ArrowRight', 'Del', 'Delete'];
constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
}
@HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
  // Allow Backspace, tab, end, and home keys
  if (this.specialKeys.indexOf(event.key) !== -1) {
    return;
  }
  let current: string = this.el.nativeElement.value;
  const position = this.el.nativeElement.selectionStart;
  const next: string = [current.slice(0, position), event.key == 'Decimal' ? '.' : event.key, current.slice(position)].join('');
  if (next && !String(next).match(this.regex)) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
@HostListener('input', ['$event'])
public onInput(event) {
  let val: string = this.el.nativeElement.value;
  const position = this.el.nativeElement.selectionStart;
  if(event.data == '.' && val.split('.').length > 2){
    console.log("This restricts the additional decimal.")
    this.el.nativeElement.value = val.slice(0, position-1);
  }
  
  if (val.length == 9 && !val.includes('.')) {
    this.el.nativeElement.value = val + '.';
  }
}

}
```

For the mobile devices, along with the above angular directive, use the inputmode, to display the numpad.