# Limit the input field to two decimals

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angularjs-directive, ionic2

I'm using Ionic/Angular for a hybrid app and in a form and I'm trying to limit the amount input field to max two decimals. However, the following code allows only to enter full numbers.

```
<ion-input ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/" step="0.01" type="number" (keypress)="validateNumber($event)" placeholder="{{ 'Price_in_CHF' | translate }}" [(ngModel)]="productPrice"></ion-input>
```

```js
validateNumber(event: any) {
    let input = String.fromCharCode(event.charCode);
    const reg = /^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/;

    if (!reg.test(input)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to use step=".01" instead of step="0.01".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit input field to two decimal places - Angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50722368/limit-input-field-to-two-decimal-places-angular-5)

Comment: @TestDPSjaksf it is still not working. It is limited to full numbers only

Answer (score 2):

you can create your custom directive

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
  selector: '[appTwoDigitDecimaNumber]'
})

export class TwoDigitDecimaNumberDirective {
  private regex: RegExp = new RegExp(/^\d*\.?\d{0,2}$/g);
  private specialKeys: Array<string> = ['Backspace', 'Tab', 'End', 'Home', '-'];

  @Input('appTwoDigitDecimaNumber') decimal:any;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
  }
  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])

  onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    // Allow Backspace, tab, end, and home keys
    if(this.decimal){  
      if (this.specialKeys.indexOf(event.key) !== -1) {
        return;
      }
      let current: string = this.el.nativeElement.value;
      let next: string = current.concat(event.key);
      if (next && !String(next).match(this.regex)) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    }else{
      const charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
      if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 105)) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
      return;
    }
  }
```

**Usage**

```
<input type="text" [appTwoDigitDecimaNumber]="true">
```

I hope it will help you a lot.

Note : you can use it any `number` type field where you want use just add `[appTwoDigitDecimaNumber]="true"` if you dont want to use then add `[appTwoDigitDecimaNumber]="false"`.
Bacause i have use these directive in dynamic forms that why i have set it base on `true` or `false`.
You can use it in `Dynamic form` also

Comment: If any one facing issue on implement these directive then let me know i will ready to help you

Comment: Hi thank you for your response. I tried your directive but it looks like that it is not working. I don't get any error, but the input box is not limited

Comment: Hi, i have create here stackblitz link its working fine check here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jmodge?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html    can you have import it in `declaration` in `app.module.ts` file

Comment: Hi bhagwat tupe sorry but I was in holiday. however, it does still not work and I cannot access to your stackblitz. Is it possible that this does not work in Angular 2?

Comment: @Varano check these https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jmodgetwo-digit-directive

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with the following regex

```
reg = /^[0-9]{1,2}$/;
```

I hope that help you!