# Do not allow user to delete coma/dot if

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

I'm using regex from other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50722368/limit-input-field-to-two-decimal-places-angular-5), but i found a problem in my case with dot.

I want to allow user to place max 3 digits numbers then coma or dot which one I'm replacing on dot otherwise, then max 4 digits numbers and that's working perfectly.

```
export class DecimalValidator {
  private regex: RegExp = new RegExp(/(^[0-9]{1,3})+([,.][0-9]{0,4}){0,1}$/g);
  private specialKeys: Array<string> = ['Backspace', 'Tab', 'End', 'Home', 'ArrowLeft', 'ArrowRight', 'Del', 'Delete', ',', '.'];

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
  }

  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
  onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (this.specialKeys.includes(event.key)) {
      return;
    }
    const current: string = this.el.nativeElement.value;
    const position = this.el.nativeElement.selectionStart;
    let next: string = [current.slice(0, position), event.key === 'Decimal' ? '.' : event.key, current.slice(position)].join('');
    next = next.replace(/[,.]/g, m => (m === ',' ? '.' : '.'));

    if (next && !String(next).match(this.regex)) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}
```

I want to allow user to delete dot in case there aren't any numbers after a dot, but to not allow it if there are any numbers after a dot.

```
#ALLOW: 123.
#NOT ALLOW: 123.2
```

So if there are any numbers after a dot user can hit backspace as many times as he want but that nothing change in the input.

Can I do it here in this directive?

Answer (score 0):

change regex:

```
private regex: RegExp = new RegExp(/(^[0-9]{1,3})+([,.]{1}[0-9]{1,4}){0,1}$/g);
```