# Angular input tag display with always 2 decimal places with ngmodel and restrict after 2 decimal places while receiving input?

Tags: html, angular, decimal

I have the following array,

```
[{
  "label": "count1",
  "type": "number",
  "value": 25.00
}, {
  "label": "count2",
  "type": "number",
  "value": 78.00
}]
```

I am looping through the above array to render my html as below

```
<div *ngFor="let obj of data">
  <label>
    <span>{{obj.label}} </span>
  </label>
  <input type="number" onKeyPress="if(this.value.length==11) return false;" [ngModel]="obj.value| number : '1.2-2'" (ngModelChange)="obj.value=$event">
</div>
```

I should not allow the end user to enter more than 2 decimal places in input box.Also by default it should get loaded with decimal places as given in the array.

Comment: [Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50722368/limit-input-field-to-two-decimal-places-angular-5)

Comment: That doesnt work out on initial loading with decimal points in ng model. also the given directive allowing 3 deimal points..

Answer (score 0):

You try using form-control

HTML

```
<input type="number" onKeyPress="if(this.value.length==11) return false;" [ngModel]="obj.value" (ngModelChange)="obj.value=$event">
```

.ts

```
obj.value.toFixed(2));
```