# how to Limit input field to 4 decimal places?

Tags: angular

I want to limit the decimal places input such as 12.1234, after 4 , user may not allow to input number

i try to use mixlength, pipe and tofix, the result is 12.1234 but user still can input 12.123456.....

is than any way to set limit in html ?

Comment: you can use masking for that. either use jquery mask or npm package for that.

Comment: any code ? i am new, please help T_T

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50736992/6319730

Comment: <input formControlName="ODKG"  style="width:200px;" #ODKG formControlName="ODKgDropdown" class="infinity form-control"
                    id="ODKgDropdown" value="{{odKgUserInput}}" maxlength="8" (blur)="Update('ODKg',ODKG.value)">

Comment: this is my input, there is no ngModel, any other way to do the ctrl in html ??
so i don't need to handle it in ts

Answer (score 0):

Use DecimalPipe.

Decimal representation options, specified by a string in the following format:
`{minIntegerDigits}.{minFractionDigits}-{maxFractionDigits}`.

- minIntegerDigits: The minimum number of integer digits before the
  decimal point. Default is 1.
- minFractionDigits: The minimum number of
  digits after the decimal point. Default is 0.
- maxFractionDigits: The
  maximum number of digits after the decimal point. Default is 3.

`{{ value_expression | number [ : digitsInfo [ : locale ] ] }}`

https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe

Comment: i try it before, but i need to limit the input in Real Time
now i can keep input in the UI, but the result is correct