# Mat-input limit format to two decimal places

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to limit the amount of spaces after the decimal points to two numbers in a mat-input that uses a dollar amount. Currently someone can type in as many numbers as they want after the decimal point. I am not sure how to do this and looking for help with a possible solution to this.

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-59uq5a?file=app%2Fform-field-prefix-suffix-example.html)

html

```
<mat-form-field>
 <input
   matInput
  placeholder="Amount"
  type="number"
  class="example-right-align"
  [formControl]="bfastamountCtrl"
  [value]="bfastamountCtrl.value | number: '1.2-2'"
/>
 <span matPrefix>$&nbsp;</span>
</mat-form-field>
```

ts

```
bfastamountCtrl = new FormControl(null, { updateOn: 'blur' });
```

Comment: I guess your question is answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50722368/limit-input-field-to-two-decimal-places-angular-5