# event.preventDefault() is not supported in Android WebView. Any other function?

Tags: javascript, html, webview, appcelerator

In `touchmove` event, I do not want the page to scroll in WebView. But  `event.preventDefault();` is not supported in my framework. Give another solution or function. `event.stopPropagation()` and `return false` are also not supported.

This is my code:

```
window.addEventListener('touchmove', onTouchMove);

function onTouchMove(event) {
  try {
    curX = event.touches[0].pageX - startX;
    curY = event.touches[0].pageY - startY;
    gbMove = true;
    if (vertical == 0) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  } catch (err) {
    showError("touchMove " + err);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please look once below code -

window.addEventListener('touchmove', onTouchMove);

function onTouchMove(event) {
 try {
  curX = event.touches[0].pageX - startX;
  curY = event.touches[0].pageY - startY;
  gbMove = true;
  
  if (vertical == 0) {     
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
  } else {
   return true;
  }
 } catch(err) {
  showError("touchMove " + err);
 }
}

Comment: See similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30253404/jquery-preventdefault-not-working-on-android-4-4-default-browser